# How to pass value from onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know this question has been asked before and I've looked:

[How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

[how do i send data back from onPostExecute in an AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447646/how-do-i-send-data-back-from-onpostexecute-in-an-asynctask)

[how to pass the result of asynctask onpostexecute method into the parent activity android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909765/how-to-pass-the-result-of-asynctask-onpostexecute-method-into-the-parent-activit)

And I tried creating an interface to pass the value to, I also tried creating a method to assign the value through my onPostExecute and lastly I tried setting the variable directly like below, but nothing seems to work.

```
public class ClassName extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Bitmap bit;

    public void methodName() {
        new RetrieveFavIcon().execute("https://www.google.com");
        // work with 'bit' value, but bit value is null, why?
    }

    class RetrieveFavIcon extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    public TaskListener delegate = null;

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(new URL(urls[0].trim()), "/favicon.ico");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("URL return", "failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {
        if(bm != null) {
            bit = bm;
            Log.d("bitmap", "bitmap not null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any explanation why this is getting downvotes?

Comment: Try this, http://android-er.blogspot.de/2013/09/implement-callback-function-with.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use interface. when Async task will reach postExecute than interface will callback class which implement interface. interface can carry result to class.

create a interface like below:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
void processFinish(String output);
}
```

processFinish()'s argument should be according to data which you want to send to MainActivity.

implements it in MainActivity:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AsyncResponse
```

You need to pass interface to AsyncTask:

```
 new AsyncTask(this, MainActivity.this, news).execute();
```

Declare a object of interface in AsyncTask Class. assign passed interface from MainActivity to this object:

```
public Cover(AsyncResponse delegate, Context context, ArrayList<NewsWrapper>      list) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}
```

Now in postExecute :

```
delegate.processFinish(/*Your Data which you want to send in MainActivity*/);
```

override interface method processFinish() in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void processFinish(/*sent data from AsyncTask*/) {
    /*Use result here*/
}
```

Comment: I looked at that and tried using interface, it didn't work